# vagrant with ansible error

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

If I have Vagrantfile with ansible provision:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'hashicorp/precise32'
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "hosts"
    ansible.limit = 'all'
    ansible.sudo = true
  end

end
```

My hosts file is very simple:

```
[local]
web ansible_connection=local
```

and playbook.yml is:

```
---
- hosts: local
  sudo: true
  remote_user: vagrant
  tasks:
  - name: update apt cache
    apt: update_cache=yes

  - name: install apache
    apt: name=apache2 state=present
```

When I start vagrant with wagrant up I got error:

```
failed: [web] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
[sudo via ansible, key=daxgehmwoinwalgbzunaiovnrpajwbmj] password:
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Hmm looks like it is asking for the sudo password.. Have you configured that in your yml file?

Comment: add `vagrnt` to sudoers

Comment: @VladimirFejsov If you're on Ubuntu or a Debian based Linux, see [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers). The [man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) further explains it. [Kashyap](http://stackoverflow.com/users/496289/kashyap) is saying that your `vagrant` user must exist and have `sudo` privileges on the remote machine. And as [ryekayo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4114323/ryekayo) points out, you need to store the password for the `vagrant` user on the host so Ansible can retrieve it, probably in the [ansible-vault](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because ansible is assuming key based ssh authentication, however your vagrant is creating a VM is uses password based authentication.

There are two ways you can solve this issue.

You can run your ansible playbook as

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-pass
```

This will tell ansible to not assume key-based authentication, instead use password based ssh authentication and ask one before execution.